# Tesseract-OCR3.04 was corrupted at run time

Tags: c++, tesseract

I parpare to use tesserac-OCR to recongise some characters,however it can't work even though this simple code:

```
TesseractOcr::TesseractOcr(Config* config)
  : OCR(config)
  {   
      tesseract::TessBaseAPI tesseract;
  }
```

In the constructor of my  TesseractOcr class,I define a local TessBaseAPI object.When leaving the consturctor,VS2015 report:Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'tesseract' was corrupted.

[image]

The tesseract version is 3.04. It was complied by VS2015 as Win32-debug mode which matched with my work environment.
I hava no idea,anyone can help? thinks.

Comment: is that the entire program? The message says you have trashed your stack

Comment: Yes,there can ingore others.I commented all code in  base class OCR and param class Config.If i was  commented // tesseract::TessBaseAPI tesseract this ,it works well.